# How To Immediately Change Chrome Extension Icon?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've seen plugins like Adblocks which can switch plugin icon to grayscale almost with immediate tab change action.

How do I achieve this? Currently I'm doing it with detecting specific URL with content.js and then sending a message to background.js to change the icon. But this is slow and happens after 2-3 seconds after page load.

How do I do this? I've a specific list of URL wildcards on which icon has to be changed.

Answer (score 3):

The [`chrome.pageAction`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction) and [`chrome.browserAction`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) APIs allow extensions to specify tab-specific state (button tooltip, icon, popup, etc.).

You can use the [`chrome.webNavigation`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) APIs to detect navigations, or the [`chrome.tabs`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) API to detect tab state changes. Bind an event listener to either API and update the badge state in the callback:

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(function(details) {
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
        text: 'whatever',
        tabId: details.tabId  // Important for tab-specific state!
    });
});
```

(read [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#property-onCommitted-callback) to see what's available in the `details` object.)

Answer (score 0):

Your content script runs, by default, at `"document_idle"`, meaning "some time after the document is fully loaded and JS engine is idle"

If your "detector script" does not need access to DOM to decide on the icon, you can set it [to run at `"document_start"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at), before DOM is loaded:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["*://*.example.com/*"],
    "js": ["detect_url.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start"
  }
],
```

See [Content Script docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) for more details.

Alternatively, if you have `"tabs"` permission, you can listen to relevant tabs events (`onCreated`, `onUpdated`, `onReplaced`).